# jQuery not toggling contenteditable on click and a/href not disabled

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, contenteditable

I'm unable to toggle the attribute `contenteditable`. By default I've hardcoded it in the HTML code to `false` and when I click the `#edit-button` it turns to `false`. But when I click it again, nothing happens. It seems the `else`-part is never triggered.

I'm also trying to disable every `a/button href` but I'm also unsuccessful in this matter. Is the below if-statement wrong?

```
if ( $(this).is(':button') ) {
    $(this).attr('href', '#');
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#edit-button').on('click', function() {
    $('section').each(function() {
        $(this).find('[contenteditable]').each(function() {
            if ( $(this).attr('contenteditable', false) ) {
                $(this).attr('contenteditable', true);
                $('#header').focus();
                if ( $(this).is(':button') ) {
                    $(this).attr('href', '#');
                }
            } else {
                $(this).attr('contenteditable', false);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Trying to search through SO but and Google without luck.

Thankful for help.

Comment: You need to add attribute or removeAttr as contentEditable, Not to use false or true for contenteditable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
<div contenteditable="true">The quick brown fox...</div>
<br/>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Testing</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Testing</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Testing</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Testing</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Testing</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Testing</a><br/>
<br/>
<button class="disableToggle">Button</button>
<br/>
<button class="disableToggle">Button</button>
<br/>
<button class="disableToggle">Button</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<button id="toggle">Toggle Edit</button>

$("#toggle").click(function () {
    if ($("div").attr("contenteditable") == "true") {
        $("div").attr("contenteditable", "false");
        $(".disableToggle").attr("disabled", "true");
        $("a").on("click", function(e){e.preventDefault();});
    } else {
        $("div").attr("contenteditable", "true");
        $(".disableToggle").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("a").off("click");
    }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/sps4rhfn/2/)

Comment: This works, thank you. Would you know how to fix the button/href problem described above?

Comment: @AntonFlärd Are you trying to also disable all links and buttons as well?

Comment: @AntonFlärd I updated the answer and the link to [the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/sps4rhfn/2/) :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the removeAttr function.

```
$(this).removeAttr('contenteditable');

**instead of**

$(this).attr('contenteditable', false);
```

And at the time of checking attribute. You can use as

```
var attr = $(this).attr('contenteditable');
if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
  // Your existing code.
}

instead of 

if ( $(this).attr('contenteditable', false) ) {
```

// Your full code will be as:

```
$('#edit-button').on('click', function() {
   $('section').each(function() {
    $(this).find('[contenteditable]').each(function() {
        var attr = $(this).attr('contenteditable');
        if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
            $(this).attr('contenteditable', true);
            $('#header').focus();
            if ( $(this).is(':button') ) {
                $(this).attr('href', '#');
            }
        } else {
            $(this).removeAttr('contenteditable');
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that with *contenteditable* you have to set "true" and "false" as strings. Not like other attributes that can just be empty.
Try setting

```
$(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
```

and
    $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'false');

Not 100% it’s the same for all browsers but give it a shot!